# how to plot an agent attribute against time

Tags: netlogo

I am coding a traffic simulation and I want to plot a property of the patches against time. 
Can you help me with the coding?

I am trying to introduce an if clause that a monitor (representing budget) will produce a certain amount of money when the IRI or USER COST reaches a certain number.

Please, I will be glad if you could help me with this.
Hope to hear from you soon.

Kind regards,
Jephunneh Bonsafo-Bawuah.

I tried creating a monitor it reports the amount once and that's all but I wanted it to report continuously. 
I tried using a code but that didn't also work

```
to budget
ifelse IRI > 220
[ set budget 20000 ]
[set usercost 0]
end
```

the error message says
set expects two inputs

Comment: A monitor will show the result continuously automatically. If it doesn't change, then the variable or expression that it is reporting is not changing. What do you have in the code box when you created the monitor?

Comment: @JenB I have  to-report budget
                            report 0 + 20000
                          end            in the code tab that reports 20000 through the monitor.